# AVD Manager Disable CTRL+ special keys

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am using the Android Emulator, with AVD, and I want to type the character "@", I cannot do Altgr+, I can't either do alt+ctrl, because I send a different instruction (which I don't know).

I have tried the following:

1) In the edit menu, disable the option Hardware keyboard present.

2) Pressing F1, I can see some options, in settings I have change from `Send keyboard shortcuts to Emulator Controls` to Send keyboard shorcuts to Virtual Device`. The result after this one is that, Ctrl and altgr do nothing.

Comment: It's still open bug in Google issue tracker from 2017 ‍♂️ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37142228

Comment: 2020 and the issue is not fixed. Impressive Google! :D
(For API 19 AVDs at least. For latest AVDs at least we have the on-screen keyboard)